# Angular.js accessing model from controller (server validation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i now trying to migrate my legace app to Angular and now stuck with following issue.
I have this simple form:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-submit="doLogin()">
  <input type="text" name="login" ng-model="login.login" />
  <span class="errors" ng-show="loginForm.login.$error.required">Required</span>
  <span class="errors" ng-show="loginForm.login.$error.bad_login">Login or pass incorrect</span>
  <input type="password" ng-model="login.pass"/>
</form>
```

Server returns error as this type of JSON: { login: 'bad_login', pass: 'incorrect' }
And in controller:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        var model = $scope.login;
        var req = { "login": model.login, "pass": model.pass };
        $http({ method: "POST", url: "/login", data: req }).success(function (resp) {
            if(resp.status != "ok") {
                angular.forEach(resp, function (value, key) {
                    // ex: model['login'].$setValidity('bad_login', false);
                    model[key].$setValidity(value, false);
                });
            }
        });
    };
}
```

I try to mark each field in loop, not to hardcode every field by hand. but this approach not working. I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot call method '$setValidity' of undefined`, even when field is left empty i have another error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined`
So i think i need to get instance of model for every field in form, any ideas ?

Comment: If I read your code correctly, is your model 'model', not model[k]. Try to use meaningful parameter names please. Not v, k, p.

Comment: Updated my post, thank you for remark.
I guess i should have 2 models here, 1 model for each field to mark errors independently. I think i understand now that `$scope.login` is model and `$scope.login.pass` is not model, but plain string ?

Comment: Indeed, you need two models (login and pass), on which you can use $setValidity() then.

Comment: I update my post, now i guess i have 2 models, but result is almost the same

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's coming back undefined is because unless you actually specify something for $scope.login.login or $scope.login.pass to begin with, they aren't set. If you put a space and delete it, you'll see they are set as blank. What you're going to want to do is at the beginning of your controller define the login on the scope like so:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = {
        login: "",
        pass: ""
    };
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        var req = { "login": $scope.login.login, "pass": $scope.login.pass };
        $http({ method: "POST", url: "/login", data: req }).success(function (resp) {
            if(resp.status != "ok") {
                angular.forEach(resp, function (value, key) {
                    // ex: model['login'].$setValidity('bad_login', false);
                    $scope.login[key].$setValidity(value, false);
                });
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid mentioning all my form fields in controller ? I have sometimes huge huge forms and this going to be annoying thing.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but with your example i also get error: `TypeError: Object  has no method '$setValidity'`